# set custom validation in angualr when text change in input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

i create a custom validaiton for check equal email and confirm email in reactive form .

and i use that by this way in form :

```
this.changeAccountInfoFG = this.formBuilder.group({
  email: [this.accountInfo.userName, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  confirmEmail: [''],
  userGroupRefId: [this.accountInfo.userGroupRefId, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  isActive: [this.accountInfo.isActive]
}, {
  validator: MustMatch('email', 'confirmEmail')
});
```

but i not want use this validatoin by this way :

i want use this validation by this :

```
  onSearchChange(value) {
    this.changeAccountInfoFG.get('confirmEmail').setValidators(MustMatch('email', 'confirmEmail'))
  }
```

bu it show me this error:

```
    Argument of type '(formGroup: FormGroup) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]'.
  Type '(formGroup: FormGroup) => void' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'.
```

**whats the problem ? how can i sovle this problem ??**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set validation at form level.

You also need to call `updateValueAndValidity` method to recalculate the value and validation status of the control

```js
onSearchChange(value) {
    this.changeAccountInfoFG.setValidators([MustMatch('email', 'confirmEmail')])
    this.changeAccountInfoFG.updateValueAndValidity()
  }
```

Comment: it did verify. it should work. is this static validation `validator: MustMatch('email', 'confirmEmail')` works for you??

Comment: If i could able to help you, please do not forget to vote :)

Comment: @Mr-Programer please accept my answer. it worked for you. right?

Comment: ok..you responded that it worked.. thats why i was checking..let me know if i can help.